# How to use 404 page component to current url in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, routes, nuxt.js

In my nuxt project i have the following structure in my pages folder:

```js
index.vue
tools
   index.vue
   _id.vue
page-not-found.vue
```

in my nuxt config i have this on router section:

```js
router: {
        extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
            routes.push(
                {
                    name: '404',
                    path: '*',
                    component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/page-not-found.vue')
                },
            )
        },
    }
```

when i land in url other than on my pages folder, i have the url and my 404 component showed (ex: `my-domaine/other-path` show 404 content). So that i want is with my route `tools-id` i want to fetch data depend on parameter `id`, if got data, i show the page with details, but if i got no data, i want to have the same behavior as my 404 route; like, in my url i have `my-domaine/tools/parameter_value` but my pages show the 404 content.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Nuxt documentation for error pages: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/views/#error-page.

You can create a layout file called `error.vue` which serves as a base for all error pages in your site. From that layout you can reference the appropriate error component. For example:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <NuxtLink to="/">Home page</NuxtLink>
        <PageNotFound v-if="error.statusCode === 404" :message="error.message" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['error'],
        layout: 'error'
    }
</script>
```

Vue will automatically render the content of the error page on the invalid route. You can also programmatically open the error page by calling the `context.error()` method. For example:

```
asyncData ({ params, error }) {
    return axios.get(`https://my-api/posts/${params.id}`)
    .then((res) => {
        return { title: res.data.title }
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Post not found' })
    })
}
```

If you're using the `error` function inside the `asyncData` or `fetch` methods, then you can access it like I showed in the answer above, otherwise in any other method defined in the Vue instance you can access it via `this.error()`

```
export default {
    data: {...},
    methods: {
        validateRoute() {
            if (404) { 
                this.error({statusCode: 404, message: "Page not found"})
            }
        },

        axiosRequest() {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get('...');
                return response;
            } catch(err) {
                this.error({statusCode: 404, message: err.message });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is the error function exist only on async function?, cause when i try to call it direct in simple function it said that error is not defined

Comment: You should be able to access the `error()` method from the Nuxt Context - which is called `this` in Vue components (with the exception of the `fetch()` and `asyncData()` methods where you can access the context properties as shown in my answer). The Nuxt documentation here explains it well: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/internals-glossary/context/

Comment: please ^^" have a snippet code that can explain the real behavior, i can't figure out where can i use error(), i use @nuxtjs/axios, so i don't know where can i retrieve the usage of error function

Comment: I've added some more examples to my answer, hopefully they answer your question.